# How to open .cpp file with notepadqq application?

Tags: c++, text-editor, file-association, notepadqq

Currently I am using default text editor (gedit) to write C++ programs.  Now I wanted to use **notepadqq** application rather than gedit.

I have installed notepadqq.

The problem I am facing,

1. create a file called mypro.cpp (with empty code) on desktop
2. double click or open the file once you name it
3. file is opening in gedit.

what I want is, after step 2,

3. file shall open in notepadqq application

Note:
I have tried using following,

1. `gksudo gedit /etc/gnome/defaults.list`
2. Changed from

   ```
   text/x-c++hdr=ubuntusdk.desktop
   text/x-c++src=ubuntusdk.desktop
   ```

   to

   ```
   text/x-c++hdr=notepadqq.desktop
   text/x-c++src=notepadqq.desktop
   ```
3. reboot the system

But this didn't work for me.

Please help.

Comment: It is unclear what you are wanting to do. Would it be possible to reword your question to be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Hi rp, I updated..are the details OK now?

Comment: Completely OK, thanks for making that more clear. I have now posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be able to be fixed easily enough through the GUI. No commands or file edits should be needed.

In Nautilus, you can right-click the file and choose "About" (Or something similar) and set .cpp files to open in notepadqq instead of gedit. This should also work if you right-click on the file while on the desktop.

I hope I helped you!

Comment: I'm glad to help!